# Lambda Capture by Value forces all scoped object to const

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, lambda

I was intending to write a memorization pattern in C++ and ended up with the following approach

```
std::function<int(int)> Memoize(std::function<int(int)> fn)
    {
        std::map<int, int> memo;
        std::function<int(int)> helper = [=](int pos) 
        {
            if (memo.count(pos) == 0)
            {
                memo[pos] = fn(pos);
            }
            return memo[pos];
        };
        return helper;
    }
```

Strangely, my compiler VS 2012, refused to compile with the following error

```
1>Source1.cpp(24): error C2678: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

It seems to me that the compiler deliberately captures everything by value as a const object. I cannot find any documented reference to this behavior.

Can any one help me understand what is possibly happening here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `memo.count(pos)`? As it stands, for any values other than 0, we always calculate and store the value, even if it already exists.

Comment: @PhilWright: Yes, true. Actually I was trying to debug my code and while posting forgot to change it. Thanks for highlighting it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lambdas behave more or less like function objects; like a function object they have a function call operator, i.e. `operator()`. For non-`mutable` lambdas, this function is `const`:

[expr.prim.lambda]

> 5 The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression has a public
>   inline function call operator [...] **This function call operator or
>   operator template is declared `const`** (9.3.1) if and only if the
>   lambda-expression’s parameter-declaration-clause is **not followed by
>   `mutable`**.

Because entities captured by copy behave as though they were member variables of the lambda:

> 15 [...] For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type.

and non-`mutable` members **cannot** be modified inside a `const` member function ([class.this] / 1, [dcl.type.cv] / 4), if you want to modify the captured entities you will have to declare a `mutable` lambda.

As it stands your lambda looks like this:

```
class Helper
{
public:
    int operator()(int) const;
private:
    std::map<int, int> memo;
    std::function<int(int)> fn;
};
```

You can think of a `mutable` lambda as having a non-`const` `operator()`, in your case the lambda can be defined as follows:

```
std::function<int(int)> helper = [=](int pos) mutable
// etc
```

Comment: +1, perfect explanation relating lambdas with object functions (functors).

Answer (score 6):

In order to make a lambda function non-const you need to add the `mutable` keyword:

```
std::function<int(int)> Memoize(std::function<int(int)> fn)
    {
        std::map<int, int> memo;
        std::function<int(int)> helper = [=](int pos) mutable // <== HERE!!
        {
            if (memo.count(0) == 0)
            {
                memo[pos] = fn(pos);
            }
            return memo[pos];
        };
        return helper;
    }
```