# decltype() on std::move() of a value capture in a lambda results in an incorrect type

Tags: c++, clang, language-lawyer, c++17, decltype

It seems like there either is something wrong with Clang (9.0.0) or my understanding of how `decltype()` is specified to work in the standard. With reference to the following code,

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>

template <typename...> class WhichType;

template <typename T>
std::remove_reference_t<T>&& move_v2(T&& t) {
    WhichType<std::remove_reference_t<T>&&>{};
    return static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>&&>(t);
}

int main() {
    auto x = std::string{"a"};
    [v = x]() { 
        // move_v2(v);
        // WhichType<decltype(move_v2(v))>{};
        WhichType<decltype(std::move(v))>{};
    }();
}
```

The code above has the compiler output `implicit instantiation of undefined template 'WhichType<std::__1::basic_string<char> &&>'` instead of the expected `const std::__1::basic_string<char> &&` in the template parameters of `WhichType`. Using `move_v2` or `WhichType` in `move_v2` itself seems to output the correct thing though.

However, Clang also seems to do overload resolution on the `std::move(v)` expression as I expected https://wandbox.org/permlink/Nv7yXnCbqxjJMVvX. This makes some of my worries go away, but I still don't understand the behavior of `decltype()` inside the lambda.

GCC does not seem to have this inconsistency in this particular case https://wandbox.org/permlink/5mhrOzLn5XZO8LNB.

---

Could someone correct me if I'm wrong with my understading of `decltype()` or point me to the exact places where this bug manifests in clang? Seems a bit scary from first glance.  This can cause problems when used in SFINAE or something similar.

Comment: The correct result should be `const &&` because the by-value captured values of a non-mutable lambda are `const`, so your understanding is correct.  And Clang correctly does overload resolution even between `const &&` and `&&`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ydV79sx7g7l2RcjB, so it shouldn't cause too much of a problem in practice.

Comment: @L.F. Thanks, the worry I have is in the case where there is a complex partial specialization chain and someone uses decltype() to dispatch to that and pick the appropriate functionality. In this case there is a chance they might get the wrong result. And sounds like it would be very hard to debug also :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a variable become 'const' when I use a \[=\] capture (using Lambda class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064993/why-does-a-variable-become-const-when-i-use-a-capture-using-lambda-class)

Comment: @JVApen I think that is my understanding as well - this seems to be an edge case that either the compiler is not handling correctly or we are expecting incorrectly based on our understanding of decltype(). And I am not confident enough about the latter to make a judgement either way. I was hoping someone more confident about their understanding of the standard could link the relevant parts and explain the misunderstanding as an answer.

Comment: I suppose it's clang's bug. `const` seems lost as the return type of reference when using `decltype` together.

Comment: I think Clang deduces true but GCC deduces wrong, as @jVApen stated in his answer, because the function call operator of `ClosureType` is `const` rather than the captured object.

Answer (score 2):

Clang is wrong.  `decltype(std::move(v))` should be `const &&` because the cv-qualifier `v` (which is equivalent to `this->v`) is the union of the cv-qualifiers of `*this` (which is `const` in the `operator()` of a non-`mutable` lambda) and `v` (which is none), so `v` is a `const` lvalue.  Then, `std::move` converts to an xvalue of the corresponding type, so `decltype` should be `const &&`.

`decltype` behaves specially when applied to an id-expression or a member access expression (`this->v`), but that's not the case here.  `std::move(v)` is a complicated expression, so it is treated as an ordinary expression.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit of digging, and it seems to me that the answer is a bit more nuanced than some of the comments makes it seem.

First there is [this answer to an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31485150/11829247). To quote the important part:

> `[C++11: 5.1.2/14]:` **An entity is *captured by copy*** if it is implicitly captured and the *capture-default* is `=` or **if it is explicitly captured with a capture that does not include an `&`**. For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members is unspecified. **The type of such a data member is the type of the corresponding captured entity if the entity is not a reference to an object, or the referenced type otherwise.** *[..]*

Then there is [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26667544/11829247). Again quote:

> 5 The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression has a public
>   inline function call operator [...] **This function call operator or
>   operator template is declared `const`** (9.3.1) if and only if the
>   lambda-expression’s parameter-declaration-clause is **not followed by
>   `mutable`**.

I then put this together in a small test:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void foo(const std::string&) {
    cout << "void foo(const std::string&)" << endl;
}

void foo(std::string&) {
    cout << "void (std::string&)" << endl;
}

struct klaf
{
    std::string b;

    void bla() const
    {
        cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_const<decltype(b)>::value << endl;
        foo(b);
    }
};

int main()
{
    klaf k;
    k.bla();

    std::string s;
    const std::string s2;
    auto lam = [=]() {
        cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_const<decltype(s)>::value << endl;
        foo(s);

        cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_const<decltype(s2)>::value << endl;
        foo(s2);
    };
    lam();
}
```

Which outpouts (and the outputs are the same in GCC, Clang, and MSVC):

```
false
void foo(const std::string&)
false
void foo(const std::string&)
true
void foo(const std::string&)
```

`klaf::b` is (obviously) not `const`, but since the `klaf::bla` function is `const`, then `klaf::b` is treated as `const` in the call to `foo`.

The same is true in `lam` where `s` is captured by value with a type of `std::string`. However, `s2` has been declared as `const std::string` and that carries over to the type of the data member in the lambda.

In short: Capture by value in a lambda does *not* make the captured member itself `const`, but since `operator()` for the lambda is `const`, then the members are promoted to `const` in that function (unless the lambda is declared mutable).

EDIT:

Inspired by comment from @arnes I found a difference is GCC and Clang:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 12;
    auto lam = [=, ic = i]() {
        cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_const<decltype(i)>::value << endl;
        cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_const<decltype(ic)>::value << endl;
    };
    lam();
}
```

This produces `false false` in Clang, but `false true` in GCC. In other words, a capture with an initializer becomes `const` in GCC but not in Clang.

Comment: Yes but the weird thing is there is a conflict between Clang and GCC, it seems gcc is wrong because in `auto x = std::string{"a"};`  statement, type of `x` is `std::string`.

Comment: Your example does a different thing. You apply `decltype` to *variables* (which are treated specially) rather than *expressions*. If you do `std::remove_reference_t<decltype((s))>` instead of `decltype(s)`, then the resulting type is `const` in all three cases.